# Login and authenticate with Laravel Breeze + vue

Tags: laravel, vue.js, inertiajs

I am in a Laravel Breeze project trying to login in the most simple way, using breeze boilerplate.

When i go to /login2 and press post login in my network tab i get these reponses:
302 and then 200 and i dont get redirected to home or anywhere i just stary on the,
eventhough in the Controller i specify this redirect: return redirect(RouteServiceProvider::HOME);
How can i actually get the code from the controller to run and redirect me to where i am supposed to?

web.php

```
Route::inertia('login2', 'Auth2/Login2')->name('login2');
Route::post('login2', [Login2Controller::class, 'store'])->name('login2.post');
```

```
class Login2Controller extends Controller

{
    public function store(LoginRequest $request)
    {
        $request->authenticate();

        $request->session()->regenerate();

        return redirect(RouteServiceProvider::HOME);
    }
}
```

Login Component

```
<template>
    <MenuLayout>
    <div>
        <h1>Login</h1>
        <form @submit.prevent="loginForm.post(route('login2.post'))">
            <div>
                <label for="title">Username</label>
                <input type="text" id="title" v-model="loginForm.email">
                <div v-if="errors.title" class="text-red-600">
                    {{ errors.title }}
                </div>
            </div>
            <div>
                <label for="content">PW</label>
                <input type="text" id="content" v-model="loginForm.password">
                <div v-if="errors.content" class="text-red-600">
                    {{ errors.content }}
                </div>
            </div>
                    <div>
                        <label for="password">Remember password</label>
                        <input id="password" type="checkbox" v-model="loginForm.remember">
                    </div>
            <!-- stop multiclicks on form button -->
            <button type="submit">LOGIN</button>
            <Link :href="route('login2')">CANCEL</Link>
        </form>
    </div>

    </MenuLayout>
</template>

<script>




// export const store = reactive({
//     loadedModels: ""
// })

import { Link, useForm } from '@inertiajs/vue3';
import MenuLayout from '@/Layouts/MenuLayout.vue';
export default {

    components: {
    Link,
    MenuLayout,
    MenuLayout
},
    props: {
        errors: Object
    },
    setup() {
        const loginForm = useForm({
            email: '',
            password: '',
            remember: false
        })
        return { loginForm }

    },




};
</script>
```

Comment: what if you try to isolate the problem and call the route with postman (or similar)?